# Git track folder-name under specific locaiton that is marked as ignored

Tags: git

`node_modules` is a folder that ignored in my project everywhere:

```
.gitignore:

node_modules/
```

I'm doing some tests so i created multiple mock `node_modules` folders under `test` folder.

How can I tell git to not-ignore all `node_modules` folders under `test/**/*` (it can be in any level under `test/`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a negative pattern to .gitignore on a line after the pattern that excludes `node_moduels`

```
node_modules/
!test/**/node_modules/
```

Comment: i added this + git add, but i don't see in status that git started to track on them.

Comment: DOH... updating

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively configure Git to ignore the `node_modules` directory only when it is located in the root directory of your project.

In order to do this all you have to do is to add a slash in front of the `node_modules` name in `.gitignore`:

```
/node_modules/*
```

This way it won't ignore the files located in directories named `node_modules` in the `test` directory (or in other directories as well) no matter how deep they are located.